# C# Charakter kontrol

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hello as shown in the picture when the game started in the unity project healtUI I need to show the path Raw_Hp. How can I do th

[image]

Comment: So...? What is the question? What have you tried? Simply drag&drop in the field?

Comment: when the script character is formed, I can't add it so I have to show the path with C # code but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try dragging and dropping the Raw_HP element into your Healt UI place in your Hp Bar script? 
The Raw_HP is not instantiated so you can just simply drag it there.

AN EDIT TO YOUR COMMENT
So I see you instantiate/spawn your character object that has the Hp Bar script
(Althought I can see many better ways to handle this situation)
But if you want to continue with this thing, just add a GameTag to your hpbar like "GUI_HpBar" and then in your Hp Bar script do

```
void Start() {
    HealtUI = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GUI_HpBar")
}
```

This will automatically find the desired HpBar and link it.